# Instruction reordering with lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

Will the compiler reorder instructions which are guarded with a `mutex`? I am using a `boolean` variable to decide whether one thread has updated some struct. If the compiler reorders the instructions, it might happen that the `boolean` variable is set before all the fields of the struct are updated.

```
struct A{
  int x;
  int y;
  // Many other variables, it is a big struct
}

std::mutex m_;
bool updated;
A* first_thread_copy_;
// a has been allocated memory

m_.lock();
first_thread_copy_->x = 1;
first_thread_copy_->y = 2;
// Other variables of the struct are updated here
updated = true;
m_.unlock();
```

And in the other thread I just check if the struct has been updated and swap the pointers.

```
while (!stop_running){

    if (updated){
        m_.lock();
        updated = false;
        A* tmp = second_thread_copy_; 
        second_thread_copy_ = first_thread_copy_;
        first_thread_copy_ = tmp;
        m.unlock();
     }
....
}
```

My goal is to keep the second thread as fast as possible. If it sees that update has not happened, it continues and uses the old value to do the remaining stuff.

One solution to avoid reordering would be to use `memory barriers`, but I'm trying to avoid it within `mutex` block.

Comment: As an asside, I would recommend you use a [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) rather than calline `lock()` and `unlock()` manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely assume that instructions are not reordered between the lock/unlock and the instructions inside the lock. `updated = true` will not happen after the unlock or before the lock. Both are barriers, and prevent reordering.

You cannot assume that the updates inside the lock happen without reordering. It is possible that the update to `updated` takes place before the updates to x or y. If all your accesses are also under lock, that should not be a problem.

With that in mind, please note that it is not only the compiler that might reorder instructions. The CPU also might execute instructions out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what locks gaurantee so your dont have to use `updated`. On a side note you should lock your `struct` rather than code and everytime you access `a` you should lock it first.

```
struct A{
  int x;
  int y;
}

A a;
std::mutex m_;   //Share this lock amongst threads

m_.lock();
a.x = 1;
a.y = 2;
m_.unlock();
```

On second thread you can do

```
while(!stop)
{
  if(m_.try_lock()) {
    A* tmp = second_thread_copy_; 
    second_thread_copy_ = first_thread_copy_;
    first_thread_copy_ = tmp;
    m_.unlock();
  }
}
```

EDIT: since you are overwriting struct having mutex inside doesnt make sense.

Comment: The other thread runs a while loop. So if that other thread sees that the struct has not been updated, it goes on and uses the older version to do the remaining job. So, I can't eliminate the use of `updated` variable.

Comment: @user3286661 you should share your `struct A` the way you are sharing `updated` variable among threads.  You dont have to maintain one more variable if not needed.

Comment: The second thread will keep swapping pointers even if there is no update to the struct for a long time.

Comment: It still does not solve the problem that the second thread might keep swapping pointers even if there is no update.

Comment: @user3286661 when `m_.unlock()` is called in parent thread only at that point `m_.try_lock()` will be true which means your `a` is successfully updated by that time.