# Lifetime of an object created mid-scope (e.g. CriticalSection)

Tags: c++, c++03

**UPDATE:** This is NOT a duplicate of the "[Instruction reordering with lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39762802/1245420)" question. That question deals with system-provided synchronization primitive `std::mutex`, which didn't exist until C++11. I'm still stuck with C++03. Also, `std::mutex` is not scope-based; it depends on calls to its `lock()` and `unlock()` methods; my question deals with scope-based object instantiation issues, not reordering of function calls like the "[Instruction reordering with lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39762802/1245420)" question.

---

**My original question:**

My embedded software development group (<sup><sub>*which doesn't use Visual Studio!*</sub></sup>) has a small family of concurrency control classes following the usual types; e.g. `CriticalSection`. A `CriticalSection` object can be instantiated within any scope that must not execute concurrently. Its constructor claims a mutex, and when the scope exits, the object's destructor automatically releases the mutex used by that `CriticalSection`, which is important in the event that the scope exits abnormally; this is nothing earth-shattering I realize.

**My question is:** Can the compiler instantiate the object anywhere in the scope, or is it bound by spec to instantiate it at the point in control flow where it is defined? This is important: To allow maximum concurrency, the critical section must live for the smallest duration possible.

Example:

```
void MyClass::aMethod()
{
   // ...some code that can execute concurrently...
   // [Point A]

   if (something)
   {
      // ...some code that can execute concurrently and should
      // not be protected by the CriticalSection...
      // [Point B]

      CriticalSection myCS;

      // [Point C]
      // ...code that must NOT execute concurrently...
   }

   // [Point D]
   // ...more code that can execute concurrently...
}
```

The `CriticalSection` releases the mutex as the scope of the `if()` statement exits, so at [Point D] the mutex has been released. But is the compiler allowed to, perhaps for optimization purposes, instantiate the `CriticalSection` earlier than [Point B], as long as it's within the scope of the `if()` statement? If so, then I assume that to limit its scope, I would need to add an otherwise unnecessary scope to prevent that, am I correct? E.g.....

```
void MyClass::aMethod()
{
   // [Point A]

   if (something)
   {
      // [Point B]

      { // scope for critical section
         CriticalSection myCS;

         // [Point C]
      } // end scope for critical section
   }

   // [Point D]
}
```

Comment: Scopes are free. I don't see why "that would reek of cargo-cultishness"

Comment: I have to admit I dont know the answer and imho its not cargo-cultish at all to put the extra scope, in that way the next one reading the code wont ask himself the same question again

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes but I'd hate for someone to call me a cargo-cultist for doing that unnecessarily.

Comment: its not unnecessary, it adds readability

Comment: Compilers can reorder at will, unless there's a barrier. I suspect CriticalSection would be treated as a barrier, but not certain.

Comment: @phonetagger
    I have no idea why you think  anyone would accuse you of cargo-cultishness", or why you would worry about it.

Comment: @rsjaffe Since our CriticalSection is user-defined and not built into the system, I think it would be treated like any other class.

Comment: Oh, so you're not using Microsoft's version? Because I do wonder if they've baked something into their compiler about that for their version.

Comment: Cargo cult is when you do something someone else does without having a clue why they did it or how it works. Sounds like you know how scope works, so no Cargo Cult.

Comment: And scope is lots better and clearer than experimenting with something like `std::atomic_thread_fence`

Comment: Wow. I am **really** regretting mentioning anything about *cargo cults*. I just envisioned some wise C++ soul, perhaps Mystical or @LightnessRacesInOrbit, quoting directly from the C++ spec, telling me that my suspicion is correct, I cannot depend on the compiler to instantiate it exactly where placed in the scope, and it might be reordered to above [Point B]. Instead I get a bunch of talk about whether my workaround for not knowing that answer is or is not "cargo-cultish". Really wishing I had not used that term now.